# Each card is a flex layout (flex-direction: column). How to align content horizontally across cards?

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I have rows of cards. Each card is

```
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
```

A row is also flex layout as so:

```
display: flex;
align-items: stretch;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
```

so that all cards are of equal height.

The problem is how to align content across different cards horizontally. It happens naturally if the content is all the same height (effectively) however if content is of varying height, things don't line up.

[image]

Is there a way (without setting heights) to align content horizontally?

This plunker demonstrates the problem. Open in full screen to see the row of cards unwrapped. The "summary" headings would ideally all be aligned horizontally. http://plnkr.co/edit/zv6qBu0DfpK1Zq7Oe58M?p=preview

Thanks

Comment: can you post the html/css you're using so we have a [mcve]?

Comment: woops, sorry. Plunker link added.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think you can do that without setting a height or flex-basis on the flex items in `.iccard-content.flex-col.jc-fx-st`

Comment: You need to do something like this [css-only-solution-to-set-multiple-same-height-row-sections-on-a-responsive-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44129135/css-only-solution-to-set-multiple-same-height-row-sections-on-a-responsive-gri/44164542#44164542), or a script